# CRTP derived templated method call yields expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

The following example does not compile with error `error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token`. I do not understand why. I'm trying to call a derived CRTP templated method. I'm doing it this way with CRTP because you can't have `virtual` templated methods.

https://godbolt.org/z/PMfsPM

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo
{
  Foo(int xx, int yy) : x(xx), y(yy) {}
  int x, y;
};
struct Bar
{
  Bar(int xx, int yy, int zz) : x(xx), y(yy), z(zz) {}
  int x, y, z;
};

template<class Derived = void>
class Base
{
public:
  template<class T>
  std::unique_ptr<T> makeTImpl(int x, int y) {
    return std::make_unique<T>(x, y);
  }
  template<class T>
  std::unique_ptr<T> makeT(int x, int y)
  {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Derived, void>) {
      return makeTImpl<T>(x, y);
    } else {
      auto& d = *static_cast<Derived*>(this);
      return d.makeTImpl<T>(x, y); // error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
    }
  }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
public:
  Derived(int z) : _z(z) {}

  template<class T>
  std::unique_ptr<T> makeTImpl(int x, int y) {
    return std::make_unique<T>(x, y, _z);
  }
private:
  int _z;
};

int main() {
  Base b;
  b.makeT<Foo>(1, 2);
  Derived d(3);
  d.makeT<Bar>(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: @JeJo I was mostly looking for 'CRTP templated method overriding call' or something similar. Here's another hit for future searchers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeTImpl` is a function template, and is used in a dependent context. So instead of:

```
d.makeTImpl<T>(x, y);
```

you need to write:

```
d.template makeTImpl<T>(x, y);
//^^^^^^^^
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cWasx7).

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for details on which contexts require the `template` keyword.